# How to indent one line multiple times?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

Like doing `>>` 
but 5 times `>>>>>>>>>>>>`.

I am not trying to indent multiple lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:>`. Repeat `>` as many times as you want to shift. For example, if you want to shift 5 times use `:>>>>>`.

Personally, I would just use `>>` and then repeat the command with the `.` (repeat) command.

For more help see:

```
:h :>
:h >>
:h .
```

Comment: is there a hack for `:>` to indent multiple lines multiple times?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can always use cmdline-window and a count with `i`/`a` to add many `>`, e.g. `:<c-f>5><esc>`. I do not think this is really faster or better

Comment: You can do `:.,+4>>` to add two indents to the current and next 4 lines (5 lines total). Then you can `@:` to repeat it.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to Peter Rincker's answer, you can also enter visual-line mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) and use <kbd>></kbd> with a count. Unlike in normal mode, the count is used to specify how many `shiftwidth`s to indent.

If you prefer the comfort of giving a hard count, this is the only option that I'm aware of outside of a plugin or custom function.

Answer (score 3):

Press `shift-v` to visually select the line, or block of lines.

Then in normal mode press

`10>`

Answer (score 0):

The `>`takes a number input if a selection has been made.
Select a chunk of text in visual mode `v` and then `5>`to indent 5 times.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as [alpha_989's](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15773/22375)